# javascript innerHTML is not working

Tags: javascript, html

javascript innerHTML is not updating the value of input field

```js
 var i = document.getElementById("inp-text");
 i.innerHTML = 'hello';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Java Script innerHTML not working</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="inp-text" name="" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: innerHTML is a DOM property to insert content to a specified id of an element. It is used in Javascript to manipulate DOM. `innerHTML` is only used to insert new elements and `value` is used for inserting value in input field and textarea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For forms elements, you need to update `value` property for updating the content.

```js
var i = document.getElementById("inp-text");
i.value = 'hello';
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp-text" name="" />
```